# Problems CDF plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-analysis

I tried plotting a CDF plot in python. But where it should show y-values from 0 to 1, it only shows up to 0.12... And I don't know why...

```
def plot_cdf_differences(data):
    data['differences'] = data.apply(lambda e: abs(e.inner_distance_speed - e.inner_distance_lsq), axis=1)
    counts, bin_edges = np.histogram(data['differences'], bins=200, density=True)
    cdf = np.cumsum(counts)

    plt.plot(bin_edges[1:], cdf)
    plt.xlabel('Differences')
    plt.ylabel('CDF')
    plt.show()
```

[Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Po9x9.png)

Comment: Using step instead of plot is what you are looking for.

Comment: Note that `density=True` means that the total **area** of your histogram equals `1`. As the `cumsum` ends in about `0.12`, this means that the bin width (= difference between successive bin_edges, supposing they are all equal) is about `8.3`.  To get the correct `CDF`, you need to multiply all values with the bin width.  Or, alternatively, work with `density=False` and divide by the length length of the data.

Comment: Seaborn provides an out-of-the-box way to make your plot: `sns,ecdfplot(data['differences'])`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to normalize your cdf values. `cdf = np.cumsum(counts)` results in your case in values between 0-0.12. To normalize this you would have to replace that line with the following:

```
counts, bin_edges = np.histogram(data['differences'], bins=200, density=False)
cdf = np.cumsum(counts/sum(counts))
```

`np.cumsum(counts/sum(counts))` is now normalizing your values between 0 and 1.
The actual formula behind this looks like: **x_norm = (x-np.min(x))/(np.max(x)-np.min(x))** But since cumsum and histogram is used you can simplify it.
With this you should get the idea behind it.

Btw if you want your values in percent... then you can use `cdf = np.cumsum(counts/sum(counts)*100)` instead

Comment: k edited my previous post

Answer (score -1):

This library uses the maximum of the received values by default, and you need to force the maximum to be set. Try using `ylim`. [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.ylim.html)